# Action Bar Buttons Per Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Hey dudes and dudettes,

So I'm sitting here wondering, is it possible to have buttons appear and disappear on the ActionBar according to the activity or fragment a user is currently in?

For example, say we have Activity1 and Activity2 (which includes fragments X and Y)

Activity1 is the 'home screen', with nothing other than a button opening Activity2. Activity2 automatically begins in fragment X when called upon, and fragment X is a list of music. Activity2 has an additional tab to fragment Y, which is a list of music that you have starred/favorite.

Here's where it gets messy. Activity1's ActionBar contains just the AppName and the Overflow button. Fragment X's ActionBar contains the AppName and Overflow button, but now includes a search feature (which searches the full music list which can be seen in this fragment) . Fragment Y's (same activity as X but in a different tab) ActionBar contains everything X's ActionBar had, but instead the search feature only search's the starred/favorite music (which can be seen in this fragments screen).

It might seem a little complicated, but I'm looking to see if anyone has a way to accomplish this **without** using different styles/themes for each activity/fragment.

PS: How would I be able to add the functionality for the search option to show results as input is given?

Answer (score 0):

I think best option in your situation will be switching action bar to Toolbars. You can easilly create few different toolbars, and use it as actionBar (they are just view added into any layout, but basically works like action bars). They are available via support lib 21+.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

So basically you add following to start of any layout, and include layout you want (or any custom view).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_main_menu" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's worth the shot, hiding the ActionBar and using Toolbars  instead. I'll let you know how it works out, thanks once again :)